# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `phone' for #<User:0x007f35612a5448>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, railstutorial.org

I finished creating user sign-up for my new rails app and everything worked fine in development on my local machine. But on heroku the deployed app will show the homepage and most other pages except the signup_path which renders "new.html.erb". Clicking this path gives me an error telling me to check my logs.

I've checked the logs and have tried several things but don't know what to do now.  Here are the logs: http://pastebin.com/v1fVqLbL

Here's the home page which works fine, but the path attached to "sign in" doesn't

**home.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>

<div class="center jumbotron">
  <h1>sample app</h1>

  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'users/new'

  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  resources :users
end
```

And my sign up page that is supposed to load:

**new.html.erb**

```
    <% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
    <h1>Sign up</h1>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
          <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :phone, "Phone Number" %>
          <%= f.phone_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Your Password" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Application.html.erb**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                               "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
      </head>
      <body>
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        <div class="container">
          <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
            <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
          <% end %>
          <%= yield %>
          <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
          <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  VALID_PHONE_REGEX = /\A(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}\z/
  validates :phone, presence: true, length: {maximum: 15},
                   format: { with: VALID_PHONE_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

My production schema, where I believe phone is defined:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150204094519) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "phone"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["phone"], name: "index_users_on_phone", unique: true

end
```

**Heroku Migrations:**

```
20150204074511_create_users.rb                  20150204093042_add_phone_number_to_users.rb
20150204081616_add_index_to_users_email.rb      20150204094519_add_index_to_users_phone_number.rb
20150204081750_add_password_digest_to_users.rb
```

Happy to add any other files if necessary.  I'm running the final gemfile from Hartl's newest tutorial. Don't know what else to do.

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `phone' for #<User:0x007f3de7f76508>):`  Does your user have a phone attribute?

Comment: If it works locally, but not on Heroku, did you forget to run any migrations on Heroku? run `$ heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: @japed I believe so.  I followed the same steps I used to add email as I did to add phone.  I put my user.rb model above, if there is somewhere else to check I'll look.  If that was the problem I thought I'd get an error after trying to submit a sign-up, not before loading the page.

Comment: @BigRon I thought the same, have run it several times but it hasn't worked.  I did rollback two migrations in development to change phone_number to phone, then migrated in development and heroku. Didn't rollback anything in Heroku just migrated, could that hurt it? Thought migrating would take care of it.

Comment: @japed I added my production schema above, i think it is correct and has a phone attribute.

Comment: did you try rolling back this migration on heroku (`heroku run rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxx`), running it up again and restarting heroku?

Comment: Try running a rails console and check the user attr, check if the migration where you add the phone is correct. If the migration is correct and you can erase all the data un the db try doing a `rake db:reset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no such phone_field in rails, change it to text_field or number_field or telephone_field.

```
<%= f.phone_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>
```

to

```
<%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>
```

or

```
<%= f.telephone_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: There is `phone_field` in Rails http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/phone_field

Comment: yeah, aliased with 'phone_field'

Comment: @HardikHardiya no, like basia said phone_field works fine.  Changed to telephone_field to test and both worked excatly the same, still have undefined method `phone' like in the logs above.  Guessing its for :phone but I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @VirgeAssault  I'm 99% sure you messed something with migrations. Have you tried running the migration down and up as I suggested in comment above?

Comment: @basia I edited the question to include my migration folder on Heroku.  I'm not sure what version to rollback to, or what exactly to put in the VERSION=xxx part.  If I roll back to the first version and then run db:migrate on heroku, would that work if thats the problem? And what would I put as the version in the rollback?

Comment: @basia I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20150204094519` and `heroku run rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20150204093042` to rollback the two migrations that had to do with :phone, then `heroku run rake db:migrate` and it still doesn't work, is that what you meant for me to do?

Comment: :( yeah, exactly that, followed by `heroku restart` just to be sure. If this didn't work the I have no idea for now, since your code looks all good.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with migrations. I still don't understand why the migrations would not work correctly, but I was able to fix the issue in 5 minutes by deleting the heroku app and starting a new one like this:

```
heroku apps:destroy -a appname
heroku create appname
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

For anyone doing the Hartl tutorial or new to rails in general I would highly recommend trying this if you think migrations are your problem and you can't fix your current heroku app. It's unlikely you have anything in your current app that pushing to heroku and migrating again won't replicate.

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem and had to drop my database and re-run the migrations.